# PHP Captcha refuses to validate

Tags: php, captcha

I had this working, then out of the blue something changed and my php captcha fails constantly. I feel like it could be a server side issue, but I can't find anything wrong.

I'm using

1. https://www.phpcaptcha.org/
2. https://github.com/dapphp/securimage

I'm testing this at the root level of the site.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('securimage/securimage.php');

?>

<form class="" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="captcha">
    <?php
    $options = array();
    $options['namespace'] = 'captcha';
    $options['input_id'] = 'captcha_code';
    echo Securimage::getCaptchaHtml($options, Securimage::HTML_IMG);
    echo Securimage::getCaptchaHtml($options, Securimage::HTML_ICON_REFRESH);
    echo Securimage::getCaptchaHTML($options, Securimage::HTML_INPUT);
    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    { 

        $captcha_code = isset($_POST['captcha_code']) ? $_POST['captcha_code'] : null;

        $image = new Securimage();

        var_dump($_SESSION);

        if($image->check($captcha_code) == true) 
            {
                echo "Captcha was good!"; 
            } 
        else 
            {
                echo "Captcha did NOT match!";
            }

    }

?>
```

The captcha $SESSSION[]'s get set properly.

```
array(4) 
    { 
        ["securimage_code_disp"]=> array(1) 
            { 
                ["captcha"]=> string(6) "LG2BE2" 
            } 
        ["securimage_code_value"]=> array(1) 
            { 
                ["captcha"]=> string(6) "lg2be2" 
            } 
        ["securimage_code_ctime"]=> array(1) 
            { 
                ["captcha"]=> int(1457447465) 
            } 
        ["securimage_code_audio"]=> array(1) 
            { 
                ["captcha"]=> NULL 
            } 
    }
```

But no matter what i try, the if condition always fails. Returns False.

```
if($image->check($captcha_code) == true) 
            {
                echo "Captcha was good!"; 
            } 
        else 
            {
                echo "Captcha did NOT match!";
            }
```

Everything is working except the validation part. It refuses to work.

Comment: Also tested this on WAMP with same results. Validation fails every time.

Comment: With some more digging, it appears that the issue here is that my securimage files are unable to set $SESSION variables. Whereas if i do it manually it's fine.